# How to add vertical space between blocks in textblock?

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am using *beamerposter* + *textpos* packages to create a scientific conference poster. I have 3 *textblocks* serving as columns and I place *blocks* inside of them. I would like to add some vertical space between blocks, and I would prefer if Latex did that automatically. How do I do that? Is there a textpos option? Or do I need to change the theme? Or is it impossible to do automatically?

```
\documentclass{beamer} % a package for presentations
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.25]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Lankton}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{10cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\title[Conference Name]{Poster Title}

\author{John Smith\inst{1}}

\institute[University Name]{\inst{1} University Name, Country}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

  \begin{textblock}{2.4} (.3,1)

    \begin{block}{Introdus}
      \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics{msu_logo}
        \caption{A figure!}
        \label{fig:fig1}
      \end{figure}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{Some Text}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{More Text}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{block}

  \end{textblock}

  \begin{textblock}{2.4}(3.0,1)

    \begin{block}{Here we go}
      \lipsum[1]  
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{More stuff}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{block}

  \end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's the example on sharelatex: https://www.sharelatex.com/read/zcrfhydqprtc

EDIT: it turns out that `\block` is provided by beamer, not by textpos.

Answer (score 2):

To add vertical space between blocks, you could for example us `\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}`

Off-topic:

- you don't need `graphicx` with beamer
- floating specifier such as `[h!]` don't make sense in a documentclass without floating mechanism
- instead of textpos, I'd use beamer owns column mechanism

---

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.25]{beamerposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title[Conference Name]{Poster Title}
\author{John Smith\inst{1}}
\institute[University Name]{\inst{1} University Name, Country}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{Introdus}
                    \begin{figure}%[h!]
                        \includegraphics{example-image}
                        \caption{A figure!}
                        \label{fig:fig1}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{Some Text}
                    \lipsum[1]
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{More Text}
                    \lipsum[2]
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
                \begin{block}{Here we go}
                    \lipsum[1]  
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{More stuff}
                    \lipsum[2]
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]